European S&P ETF currency exchange details
I'd like to buy S&P 500 ETF on interactive brokers. Since I'm in Europe I have to buy one of ETFs denominated in EUR, CHF or GBP (like VUSA). I'd like to verify that I understand correctly how it works in terms of currency exchange. In a hypothetical situation if I have bought S&P ETF in euro and euro appreciates against the dollar while S&P 500 index stays the same price (in dollars), my ETF would go down in value?

Yes, if the value of the asset in its home currency remains the same but the value of the exchange currency changes - the value of your asset in exchange currency changes accordingly.
